# OOP Design Choices in a Web App

Tags: python, object-oriented-design, web-applications

I am about to start coding for a school project that requires me to demonstrate good OO practices in a web app.  Now, I have built a few web apps and have never felt the need to define my own classes and utilize objects (outside of classes provided by frameworks and modules) so I was looking for help in making some design decisions. It might seem like I am forcing some complexity into a project that is too simple to warrant it but it is for demonstration purposes.

The web app is dead simple.  The "database" is just a local JSON file with 2 collections which will be the "tables": users and polls. Those collections are lists of entry collections.

My first inclination is to define a "database" connection class. This class would create a file object of the JSON file in read/write mode on instantiation and contain some methods for inserting, updating, deleting, etc...

But, that is the only part of the project that I can think of that would reasonably warrant a class. Should I define user and poll classes and create objects of those every time one needs to be inserted into the database? The data would be coming into the app from an html form and I would normally just use a function to massage it into the right format and then call database function to insert it. Instantiating a class somewhere in that process seems completely unnecessary.

Users can create Polls and vote on other Polls and view the results of past Polls.  The Polls will contain a start date and end date and once the end date has passed results will be counted and stored in a "results" key in that Poll's entry collection.

There are only 2 entities in this app: Users and Polls. So, more specifically I am asking should I create a database connection class with insert,update etc methods OR classes for Users and Polls that have methods like vote() and update() that then interact with the JSON file

Where would classes best be implemented here?

Comment: The database is a detail. What you need if you're going to show off proper OOP practices is behavior. What can you do with users and polls? Storing the data is not interesting (and you should look into the repository pattern).

Comment: Users can create Polls and vote on other Polls. Polls will eventually expire and the results need to be stored in the "results" key in that Poll's entry's collection.

Comment: What exactly do you have to do? There's no way to tell you how you should architecture your application without knowing what you have to accomplish.

Comment: I also think your question is way too broad, you're essentially asking for an introduction to oriented object programming, and you could write a book as an answer to that question.

Comment: The question is definitely too broad. An answer could either give you one of many approaches (in which case, which answer is 'correct'?) or a list of things to look into.

Comment: Object-orientation is not specific to web applications.  The same practices that you would apply generally to any OO application also apply to web applications.

Comment: By the way, while your domain model is extremely simple, it's enough to allow you to implement one, i.e. have classes for `User`, `Poll` and probably others.

Comment: Not really looking for an intro to Object Oriented Programming. There are only 2 entities in this app: Users and Polls. So, more specifically I am asking should I create a database connection class with insert,update etc methods OR classes for Users and Polls that have methods like vote() and update() that then interact with the JSON file.

Comment: No, Users, Polls, etc. should not interact with the 'database'. More things to look up: SOLID principles.

Comment: @doubleYou I don't think it's a simple as this. If you have a rich domain with a lot of business rules to apply, sure, you're probably going to abstract persistence through a Repository. However, if you only have a simple CRUD application, then the Active Record pattern is possibly a better idea, otherwise you're just going to build an over-engineered mess.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand OO design is not specific to web apps. I am asking what entities would be best defined as classes

Comment: You've posed a false dilemma here between a database connection class and entity classes.  No such disparity exists; *you will always have entity classes, regardless of your chosen persistence mechanism.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey So, a database connection class, User class and Poll class?

Comment: That's probably what this will look like, yes.  Note that, if you use a database, you'll need some object-relational mapping to get your classes into database records.  I don't know Flask, so I don't know if it provides this out of the box or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I stated in the question that persistent data will be stored in a local JSON file. I want to code the interaction with this data myself so I can have as much opportunity to demonstrate OO design

Comment: @DylanD. That's sort of the point of everyone though: it's completely irrelevant to OO whether you persist the data only in memory, in a file or in a database (or even not at all).

Comment: @VincentSavard: You're right. I was operating under the (probably unjustified) assumption that the simple model was just a stand-in to demonstrate some good OO - but I guess active record would be easy enough to justify here, even if OP was challenged on it.

Comment: @DylanD.: yes, the DB is really not a good place to demonstrate OO, because it sits at the edge of the application where you're leaving the OO world and translating your model into something else. Focus on the domain logic (users, polls, voting, registering, calculating results, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The "database connection" class is already provided by the driver / DBI.

I'd concentrate on a proper data model: what entities do you have? How do they interact?

One is obviously the domain layer: users, polls, votes, etc.

Another is the web app structure: pages and interactions. They are mostly dictated by the web framework you take, if you take something like Django. They're more up to you if you take something like web.py.

A final note: OOP may be a useful tool, but it's not an end to itself. Don't over-complicate your classes. Also, define your data first, and all else will follow much more easily.

Comment: Yeah the structured data is already defined. Yeah I don't think this project requires what I am trying to do but it is required.

Comment: Also, this is a simple Flask app and the 'database' is just a JSON file in the root directory.  I would be designing the interaction with that file myself.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the data-first approach to do OOP. Object in OOP have *behaviors*, not data. A *behavior* is something derived from requirements. In this case: voting, create poll, even show results of poll.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you get a good starting point with a bunch of answers to some key questions:

1) What are the `Nouns` / `Subjects` in the sentences describing the system?

2) What is the behaviour ascribed to these `subjects`?

3) What are the relationship between these `subjects`?

Two `subjects` are mentioned by you:

- `Users`
- `Polls`

So (1) is answered.

Maybe this is enough to describe the system you are going to build.

You should neglect the fact - at least for the moment -  that you are building a webapp; forget about `Classbased Views`, `Managers` etc.

What could `Users` do? Is there any kind of `Authentication` to your system going on? Is there any kind of `Authorization` going on? If so, are there differences between `Users`? When there are different Roles involved, how should they be represented? These and more questions are to be asked to give an exhausting answer to (2).

Regarding to (3): What do `Users` with Polls? Do they `create`, `participate`, `delete polls`? Is `starting a poll` a behaviour of `User` or of `Poll`?

These and more questions help you get *a*) a good understanding of the `domain` for which you are creating a solution and *b*) help you design an `object oriented` system.

The key for `OOP` is grouping data and (modifying) behaviour *together*.

---

When you modeled your `domain`, putting your model of the world into a web application or a desktop application, console application or whatever is secondary and should be easy.